# Clearing input text field on enter or search button?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I've got a form that lets my user search. I'm using jQuery to append the search results lower in the page without reloading the page. So, I've got this:

```
isbn.php:
    <form method="post" action="ajax.php" name="searchISBN" id="searchForm"> 
        <input type="text" name="isbn" placeholder="Search..." />
        <input class="myaccount" id="doSearch" name="doSearch" type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

The problem is, I need that input text search field to clear when the user hits the Search button or hits enter. Both hitting enter and the Search button execute the search, so it must clear when either action happens.

But, I'm absolutely stumped.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

**Edit:**
I've tried what Treffynnon suggested. The problem there is, I've disabled the search button from actually loading ajax.php. So, when I use that code, it stops the page from staying on isbn.php and it loads ajax.php . This is the code that loads the search results.

```
isbn.php:
<script>
// attach a submit handler to the form
$("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {
// stop form from submitting normally
event.preventDefault(); 

// get some values from elements on the page:
var $form = $( this ),
term = $form.find( 'input[name="isbn"]' ).val(),
//term = "isbn",
url = $form.attr( 'action' );
    $.post( url, { doSearch: "Search", isbn: term } ,
        function( data ) {
            var content = $( data );

          $( "#result" ).append( content );

      }
    );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#searchForm').submit(function(){
    // do search loading code here and then
    $('input[name="isbn"]').val('');
});
```

Try this based on your update:

```
// attach a submit handler to the form
$("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {
// stop form from submitting normally
event.preventDefault(); 

// get some values from elements on the page:
var $form = $( this ),
$term_input = $form.find('input[name="isbn"]'),
term = $term_input.val(),
//term = "isbn",
url = $form.attr( 'action' );
    $.post( url, { doSearch: "Search", isbn: term } ,
        function( data ) {
            var content = $( data );

          $( "#result" ).append( content );
      }
    );
    $term_input.val('');
});
```

Comment: I'm positive it's my bad coding that won't let this solution work. Could you please have a look at the edit I made to the original post?

Comment: Nevermind! I just added $('input[name="isbn"]').val('');
 to the end of my existing jQuery, and that did it! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!

Comment: This revision of the code seems a lot more clean than just adding $('input[name="isbn"]').val(''); to the end of my code. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad you like it. I always aim to minimise the number of DOM traversal method calls my code makes as this saves the users browser considerable processing.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden variable to achieve this as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="ajax.php" name="searchISBN" id="searchForm">          
    <input type="text" name="isbn_holder" placeholder="Search..." />         
    <input type="hidden" name="isbn"/>
    <input class="myaccount" id="doSearch" name="doSearch" type="submit" value="Search" />     
</form> 

$('#searchForm').submit(function(){     
    $('input[name="isbn"]').val($('input[name="isbn_holder"]').val()); 
    $('input[name="isbn_holder"]').val(''); 
});
```

Comment: This would work, but it is more complicated and would use fractionally more proc time searching the DOM for two elements instead of just one.